# Using Timer with Backgroundworker to ensure the doWork method is called

Tags: c#, locking

I have a windows forms application in which a backgroundworker is called again and again.
I need to avoid concurrent access of the code in dowork method for the backgroundWorker; but also need to ensure that the code in the dowork method is called; hence I cannot simply avoid running the backgroundworker altogether if it is busy.

The code is provided below with detailed comments:
The code as it is works nicely; Please evaluate the code and this way of achieving the intended; Please let me know of any potential problems,code smells, design flaws or better way of doing this. Any kind of comments, answers will be of great help.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
 {
  public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
    // this timer calls bgWorker again and again after regular intervals
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmrCallBgWorker;

    // this is our worker
    BackgroundWorker bgWorker;

    // this is the timer to make sure that worker gets called
    System.Threading.Timer tmrEnsureWorkerGetsCalled;

    // object used for safe access
    object lockObject = new object();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // this timer calls bgWorker again and again after regular intervals
        tmrCallBgWorker = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        tmrCallBgWorker.Tick += new EventHandler(tmrCallBgWorker_Tick);
        tmrCallBgWorker.Interval = 100;

        // this is our worker
        bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        // work happens in this method
        bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bg_DoWork);
        bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bg_RunWorkerCompleted);

    }

    void bg_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Complete");
    }

    void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // does a job like writing to serial communication, webservices etc
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    void tmrCallBgWorker_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject))
        {
            try
            {
                // if bgworker is not busy the call the worker
                if (!bgWorker.IsBusy)
                    bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
            }

        }
        else
        {

            // as the bgworker is busy we will start a timer that will try to call the bgworker again after some time
            tmrEnsureWorkerGetsCalled = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(tmrEnsureWorkerGetsCalled_Callback), null, 0, 10);

        }

    }


    void tmrEnsureWorkerGetsCalled_Callback(object obj)
    {
        // this timer was started as the bgworker was busy before now it will try to call the bgworker again
        if (Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject))
        {
            try
            {
                if (!bgWorker.IsBusy)
                    bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
            }
            tmrEnsureWorkerGetsCalled = null;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmrCallBgWorker.Start();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I needed something similar, in that I had code that was going to periodically check the database for new records and notify the user with baloon tips.  Checking the database every n-secs caused a pause in the UI that I didn't want the user to experience so I moved the procedure to a thread.

I had a System.Windows.Forms.Timer tick event, where the Thread was created something like (leaving out all the exception handling etc):

```
TIMER_TICK(object sender, EventArgs){
    Thread checkNow=new Thread(ProcessAutoCheck)
    checkNow.IsBackground=true;
    checkNow.Start();
    checkNow.Join(500);
}
```

Then in the ProcessAutoCheck method, I used the lock approach to prevent thread contention:

```
**lock**(lockObject){
{
....
```

The program worked as designed, and I didn't consume resources with threads.  It wasn't the fanciest solution.  I learned a lot from [Threading in C# - By Joseph Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).  Complete book online.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't enter the lock, this implies that the "work-queue" is getting backed up, right? This means that work is not occurring fast enough, so it's possible that `tmrEnsureWorkerGetsCalled` might get overwritten if `tmrCallBgWorker` fires twice while a single long-running job prevents the lock from being entered. The overwritten timer will live until the GC cleans it up, and will be lost. Therefore it has failed in its job to ensure that its delegate is executed.

If you really need to ensure anything you fire into this code gets executed, why not use a Queue or ConcurrentQueue rather than creating an implicit queue via the use of timers?